# Mixed up my Two Models, Null Reference in Post Request (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to present a table with a list of rows from the database, as well as a small form option for the user to add an additional db row. I made two Models in order to both hold the table rows and capture the form. I'm not having problems with the table model, just the form model.

So I'm confident the problem is in my Controller; I am new to MVC and this is the first time I've seen two models in the same VM... I've been going back and forth making small changes to things, but I keep getting a Null Reference Error in my Controller.

VM:

```
namespace User.ViewModel
{
    public class UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel
    {
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class TemplateModel
    {
        public UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel NewTemplate { get; set; }
        public List<UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel> Templates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View (UploadDocumentTemplates.cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNewTemplate", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "NewTemplateForm"}))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" rows="5" id="TemplateName" value="@Model.NewTemplate.TemplateName">
          <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comments" name="@Model.NewTemplate.Comments"></textarea>
          <button id="AddTemplate" onclick="AddNewTemplate()" name="Add Template">Add Template</button>
    </div>
}

<table>
    <tbody>
    @{ foreach (var template in Model.Templates)
    {
         <tr id="tr_@template.DocumentTemplateId">
         <td>@template.TemplateName</td>
         <td>@template.Comments </td>
         <td>@template.IsActive </td>
    }

<script>
function AddNewTemplate() {
            $("#NewTemplateForm").submit();
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class UserController : Controller
    {
public ActionResult UploadDocumentTemplates()
        {
            var model = entity.DocumentTemplates.Select(x => new UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel()
            {
                DocumentTemplateId = x.DocumentTemplateId,
                TemplateName = x.TemplateName,
                Comments = x.Comments,
            });
    
            var _obj = new TemplateModel();

            var templatelist = _entities.GetTemplates();
            _obj.Templates = new List<UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel>();

            foreach (var template in templatelist)
            {
                _obj.Templates.Add(new UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel()
                {
                    TemplateName = template.TemplateName,
                    Comments = template.Comments,
                });
            }

            _obj.NewTemplate = new UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel();
    

            return View(_obj);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddNewTemplate(TemplateModel vModel)
        {
            var template = new DocumentTemplates();


            template.TemplateName = vModel.NewTemplate.TemplateName;
            template.Comments = vModel.NewTemplate.Comments;
    
            entity.DocumentTemplates.Add(template);
            entity.SaveChanges();


            return View("~/User/UploadDocumentTemplates.cshtml", vModel);
        }
}
```

I hit a Null Reference at this line in my Post method in the Controller:

```
template.TemplateName = vModel.NewTemplate.TemplateName;
```

The vModel.NewTemplate.TemplateName is null. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you so much!

SOLUTION:

The NRE did get fixed with Andy's help (see answer). My further issue was fixed after I populated the new VM with the fields I was using in my form.

```
namespace Example.Areas.ViewModel
{
    public class UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel
    {
        public long DocumentTemplateId { get; set; }
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }

    }

    public class TemplateModel
    {
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase TemplateFile { get; set; }

        public List<UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel> Templates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the controller I populated the TemplateModel and sent that to the View:

```
public ActionResult UploadDocumentTemplates()
        {

            var templateList = Repository.GetTemplates();

            var _obj = new TemplateModel
            {
                Templates = templateList.Select(x => new UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel()
                {
                    DocumentTemplateId = x.DocumentTemplateId,
                    TemplateName = x.TemplateName,
                    Comments = x.Comments
                }).ToList()
            };

            return View(_obj);
        }
```

Then I put @using Example.Areas.ViewModel.TemplateModel on my View and used Model.Templates for the table, and Model.TemplateName and Model.Comments in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a breakpoint in the line where you hit the Null Reference and check if `vModel.NewTemplate` has a valid instance.

You can add a constructor in `TemplateModel` class to create a new instance of `UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel()`

```
namespace User.ViewModel
{
    public class UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel
    {
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }

    public class TemplateModel
    {
        public TemplateModel()
        {
            NewTemplate = new UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel();
        }

        public UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel NewTemplate { get; set; }
        public List<UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel> Templates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

OR

create an instance after instantiating `template`:

```
var template = new DocumentTemplates();
template.NewTemplate = new UploadDocumentTemplatesViewModel();
```

Comment: The first option did remove the null exception error! I put a breakpoint in the Post and my Comments and TemplateName fields are null when submitting; the VM i'm passing has null values. Can you tell why that is?